# Convert the array with nested arrays to the new array without nested arrays (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, frontend

I have the array **"arrs" with nested arrays** like below:

```js
let arrs = ["Apple", ["Peach", "Grape"], [["Pear", "Kiwi"], ["Lemon"]]];
```

Now, I want to convert the array **"arrs"** to the new array **"newArr" without nested arrays** like below:

```js
let newArr = [ "Apple", "Peach", "Grape", "Pear", "Kiwi", "Lemon" ];
```

I created the code to convert **"arrs"** to **"newArr" without nested arrays**:

```js
let newArr = [arrs[0], arrs[1][0], arrs[1][1], arrs[2][0][0], arrs[2][0][1], arrs[2][1][0]];

console.log(newArr); // [ "Apple", "Peach", "Grape", "Pear", "Kiwi", "Lemon" ]
```

This is **the full runnable code**:

```js
let arrs = ["Apple", ["Peach", "Grape"], [["Pear", "Kiwi"], ["Lemon"]]];

let newArr = [arrs[0], arrs[1][0], arrs[1][1], arrs[2][0][0], arrs[2][0][1], arrs[2][1][0]];

console.log(newArr); // [ "Apple", "Peach", "Grape", "Pear", "Kiwi", "Lemon" ]
```

However, I want to make this code **simpler, cooler or clever**. Are there any ways to do this?

```js
let newArr = [arrs[0], arrs[1][0], arrs[1][1], arrs[2][0][0], arrs[2][0][1], arrs[2][1][0]];

console.log(newArr); // [ "Apple", "Peach", "Grape", "Pear", "Kiwi", "Lemon" ]
```

Comment: `arrs.flat(2)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **"flat()"** with **"2"**:

```js
let arrs = ["Apple", ["Peach", "Grape"], [["Pear", "Kiwi"], ["Lemon"]]];

let newArr = arrs.flat(2);

console.log(newArr); // [ "Apple", "Peach", "Grape", "Pear", "Kiwi", "Lemon" ]
```

In addition, you can use **"flat()"** with **"Infinity" for any depth of nested array**.

```js
let arrs = ["Apple", ["Peach", "Grape"], [["Pear", "Kiwi"], ["Lemon"]]];

let newArr = arrs.flat(Infinity);

console.log(newArr); // [ "Apple", "Peach", "Grape", "Pear", "Kiwi", "Lemon" ]
```

Comment: Let's hope non of the strings in the array contain a comma.

Comment: Very nice and uncommon way!

Comment: @Ivar, you right my bad

Comment: @Ivar, you right. If string contain a comma, my way with join() and split() don't work. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: `["Apple", ["Peach", "Grape"], [["Pear", "Kiwi"], ["Lemon"]]].toString().split(',')` - also works